# Inserting a row if a certain value is not already in the database with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a list of people and their information, first name, last name, email, phone, etc....

For whatever reason, when my co-worker imported this list into the database, he didn’t get everybody in there.  Now, it’s up to me to get the ~500 people who didn't make it in to the system.  I believe that the quickest way to do this would be to do something like “Insert this person if there is NOT already a phone number of ‘foobar’.”

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?  I’ve tried doing this:

```
if not exists(Select 1 from <My Table Name> where phone = '1234567890')
Begin
    <Code to insert new person>
End
```

But MySQL told me that there was an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF not exists(SELECT 1 FROM  WHERE pphone = '1234567890' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Just use `insert ignore` or `insert on duplicate key update`.  Here is an example:

```
insert into <my table name>(phone, . . . )
    Select '1234567890', . . .
    on duplicate key update phone = phone;
```

The `on duplicate key update` clause does nothing, but the `insert` will not return an error.

EDIT:

Okay, the above won't work because you can't declare the phone number to be a duplicate.  Instead, you can do this:

```
insert into <my table name>(phone, . . . )
    Select '1234567890', . . .
    from dual
    where not exists(Select 1 from <My Table Name> where phone = '1234567890');
```

Comment: but the phone column isn't unique.  there are sometimes when i need to enter the same person twice.... just not in this case.  Does that matter?